# How can I help git for Windows better handle a repository sitting on a Linux Samba share?

Tags: linux, windows, git

So I work with a Linux VM, I have several repos there with code that I run on the VM. I have a Samba share setup on the VM so I can access the repos from a Windows machine and edit them in Windows. There are many reasons why I have this setup but that would be beyond the scope of this question.

The editing experience is rather good but there is one thing left that's an annoyance: I use Atom on Windows to edit my files and it is great at handling changes within a file using git diff internally. However it colors a number of files as having changed when they have not.

To troubleshoot, I opened a command line on the Windows box and ran `git status` on the repo, it incorrectly showed a ton of files changed when there are actually no uncommitted changes in the repo. I do all of my git operations on the Linux box but it would be nice to at least have consistent status.

Is there some kind of git config on either the Linux or Windows side that I could use to make the two a little more compatible?

Comment: Do you have a `.gitattributes` for the repository?  What do you have `core.autocrlf` set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after digging some more, I've found the issue was due to different file mode flags because of my Samba configuration. I was able to fix things by disabling the fileMode option at the repo level:

```
git config --unset core.fileMode
```

And setting it globally on the Windows box:

```
git config --global core.fileMode true
```